# Creating multiple average price columns for data on sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

[image]

I created a table called 'stocks' with the stock price information for 5 different automobile companies over a period of 6 days. For each day, the stock price has been taken at 3 different time intervals. I've found a way to code the average stock price of each company for 1 day, but I'm not sure how to create more columns so that I have the average stock price of each company for each day, i.e. the columns will be: name, avg price 2020/09/08, avg price 2020/09/09, avg price 2020/09/10 etc. The table of data I'm using has data collected over 6 different days - part of it is shown below.

[image]

My code is shown below and the output so far is shown at the very top.

```
SELECT name, SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10) AS 'date', ROUND(AVG(price), 2) AS 'average price'
FROM stocks
WHERE SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10) = '2020:09:08'
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Your sample data only has one date, so it is a little confusing what you want to do.

Comment: At the top it shows the output from my code and at the bottom the table shows my sample data. Sorry its a little confusing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT name, 
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10) = '2020:09:08' THEN price END), 2) AS [average price 2020:09:08], 
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10) = '2020:09:09' THEN price END), 2) AS [average price 2020:09:09], 
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10) = '2020:09:10' THEN price END), 2) AS [average price 2020:09:10] 
FROM stocks
WHERE SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10) BETWEEN '2020:09:08' AND '2020:09:10'
GROUP BY name;
```

Just like your previous question I advise you to change the format of your dates to `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` so you don't need string functions to handle dates.

You can update the table like this:

```
UPDATE stocks
SET date_time = REPLACE(SUBSTR(date_time, 1, 10), ':', '-') || SUBSTR(date_time, -9)
```

If you update the table then the query can be simplified with the function `DATE()` to extract the date part of the datetimes:

```
SELECT name, 
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN DATE(date_time) = '2020-09-08' THEN price END), 2) AS [average price 2020:09:08], 
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN DATE(date_time) = '2020-09-09' THEN price END), 2) AS [average price 2020:09:09], 
       ROUND(AVG(CASE WHEN DATE(date_time) = '2020-09-10' THEN price END), 2) AS [average price 2020:09:10] 
FROM stocks
WHERE DATE(date_time) BETWEEN '2020-09-08' AND '2020-09-10'
GROUP BY name;
```

Comment: Is there code I could use to change the format of my dates instead of deleting all entries and reentering them manually?

Comment: SELECT name, ROUND(AVG(price WHERE date_time = '2020-09-08'), 2) as 'avg price 2020-09-08';   ------ I tried this code now to replace the original answer you had posted but I just can't get it to work; how does changing the date format help me to find the average for each date?

Comment: `AVG(price WHERE date_time = '2020-09-08')` is not syntactically correct. You need a CASE expression. Check my query.

Comment: If you did the UPDATE then check my 2nd query.

Comment: @GuntashMangat there was a typo in the WHERE clause of my 2nd query. Check now.